# Expected Values, Variance and Covariance

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, expected-value, covariance

I have come across this theorem on bayesian updating.

Suppose there is a random variable *r* of law *N* (rbar, 1/a). 
Also, $$x_i = r+\epsilon_i $$ where the error term is distributed N(0,1/b).

Then:

[image]

I have no clue about how to proceed ahead and looking for guidance.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I am looking for r|x. So far, I have E[r] = rbar and Var[r] = 1/a. I am looking for var[x], cov[r,x].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming independence between the error term and $r$:
$$\operatorname{cov}(r,x_i)=\operatorname{cov}(r,r+\epsilon_i)=\operatorname{cov}(r,r)+\underbrace{\operatorname{cov}(r,\epsilon_i)}_0=\operatorname{var}(r)$$

Similarly,
$$\operatorname{var}(x_i)=\operatorname{cov}(x_i,x_i)=\operatorname{cov}(r+\epsilon_i,r+\epsilon_i)=\operatorname{var}(r)+\operatorname{var}(\epsilon_i)$$

And, you can substitute these into the conditional density formula.